# Falling back to serving static content in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm using tornado and I have a setup like this:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/wiki/(.+)", WikiHandler),
    (r"/static/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": "./static/"})
], template_path = 'templates')
```

The problem I want to solve now is to forward select queries from `/wiki/` to the a static handler in certain circumstances. Right now, the handler looks like this:

```
def get(self, path):
    passthroughName = os.path.join ('content', path)
    if os.path.exists (passthroughName):
        self.write (open (passthroughName, 'rb').read ())
        self.finish ()
        return
    else:
        # Do some stuff
```

What I would like to do is to have a `StaticFileHandler` which is invoked first for paths in `/wiki/`, and if it fails, then the request gets forwarded to my handler. Is there some easy configuration way to do this, or do I have to subclass the `StaticFileHandler` and handle a 404 in there manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to have one handler seamlessly delegate to another, and StaticFileHandler is especially difficult to integrate in this way because of the way it assumes a static mapping between URLs and Etags (if the files on disk can be modified while the server is running, you probably don't want StaticFileHandler!). My first recommendation would be to design your URL space so that you can distinguish the static and dynamic portions by a regex on the URL.

If you can't do that, it's probably better to extend the handler you're currently using to add the features you need from StaticFileHandler than to try and rig up something that combines two separate handlers.